# Event not fired when trying to fire event from a component to his grandparent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to emit an event to the grandparent of a component, to do so I wanted to emit an event from the grand child to his parent, and then emit another event to his parent.

However, I keep getting this error without knowing why when I am emitting from the grand child component..

> TypeError: Cannot read property '$emit' of undefined

I have three components here (from the grand parent to his grand child) :

**Grand parent :** "Edit"

**Parent:** "Menu"

**Child :** "modal-new-item"

The grand child component (modal-new-item) emits an event after making an axios post request like this :

```
axios
                    .post('/menusV2/newItem', {
                    orderId: this.order.orderId,
                    type: this.newType,
                    itemId: this.newItem.value,
                    meal: this.newMeal,
                    category: this.newCategory,
                    noOfServing: this.newNoOfServing
                    })
                    .then(function(){
                            this.$emit('newItem');
                            this.onReset();
                    })
                    .catch(function (error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
```

The parent (menu) of the grandchild component receives the event and emits another event like this :

Modal-new-item is the grand child component, and his parent (menu) receives the event like this :

```
<modal-new-item :order="order" :show="showModal" @newItem="newItem"></modal-new-item>
```

And emits the event to his parent component (Edit) like this :

```
    newItem(){
        this.showModal = false;
        this.$emit('newItem');
    },
```

And the grand parent component (Edit) receives the event from the previous component (menu) like this :

```
            <Menu @newItem="refreshMenu"  @itemDeleted="refreshMenu" :order="menu" :menuItems="items" :specifications="specifications" :nutritionalValues="nutritionalValues"></Menu>
```

What I am doing wrong ? I don't understand the error thrown in the console by the grand child component.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the way you're declaring the function.

When you use ES5, `this` is referring to the function. You want to refer to the component, so you need to bind it differently.

`function () {}` -> `this` refers to this function's scope.
`() => {}` -> `this` is preserved, referring to the component.

Change this:

```
.then(function(){
                 this.$emit('newItem');
                 this.onReset();
               })
```

To this:

```
.then(() => {
             this.$emit('newItem');
             this.onReset();
            })
```

More reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

To clarify a little bit more, the error was thrown because it was expecting the function scope to have an $emit property. By preserving the `this` binding, it will check the component for an $emit property, which it has.